# Pass image from an email to image viewer in Xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios

We have an iPhone app that can display an image dataset and pass it to an UIImageviewer - however we could do with a rough pointer.  If the user was sent the dataset (image) via email as an attachment how could we pass that onto the app to be displayed.  These are not regular jpeg/png/bmp images - more datasets which need to go through / use a set of libraries to be displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can launch an application if that application registers its own URL scheme.  However, I'm not sure how you would embed your own scheme into an email attachment.

http://mobileorchard.com/apple-approved-iphone-inter-process-communication/
http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html

On a related note, I've noticed that you have been asking a lot of questions regarding DICOMs and iOS devices, trying to develop your own app, because you have a particular (email-centric) workflow not supported by existing PACS.  It seems like you've already developed your own app, so congratulations are in order.  If at any time, you decide that it may be more trouble than its worth, feel free to check out ours.

http://nephosct.com

Currently we bootstrap off of OsiriX as our server, but that should be fixed when we release a platform independent version (hopefully within a week).  We would also be happy to work with you to add features to the app so that it supports your daily workflow.